# i want too make wordpress post stay published but don't want to show in any page??By code?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating wordpress post through code:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_title`,`post_content`,`post_status`,`post_type`) VALUES ( 'Hello','Please Do Not Delet this Post','publish','post')";
dbDelta( $sql2 );
```

I want to make wordpress post stay published too but don't want to show in any page by code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You give posts publish status and your pages shows posts default published ones. You have to change your theme's default query;

It's default query

```
$query = new WP_Query();
```

Maybe you change it like

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => '' ) );
```